# Google drive api python - how to get the sharable link of a downloaded document

Tags: python, google-drive-api

i am downloading some documents from google drive then i need to procces the data locally, after processing the data i need to get the sharable link of the downloaded documents and append it to a spreadsheet with the resulting proccesed data, my actual code is here

```
import os
import pickle
import os.path
import io
import shutil

from lector_nombre import lectorNombre
from Tablas import lectorTablas
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def main():

    #----------------------Google drive auth-----------------------------
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    #-----------------------Download the files---------------------
    
    # ID DE LA CARPETA A DESCARGAR
    query = "'1qQ3245SwqSAOeqsuBdsh-ZFCqm' in parents"

    response = service.files().list(q=query,
                                spaces='drive',
                                fields='files(id, name, parents)').execute()
    
    for document in response['files']:
        #file_id = service.files.list()
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=document['id'])
        fileName = document['name']
        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print(document['name'])
            print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
            print("--------------")
            fh.seek(0)
            with open(fileName, 'wb') as f:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fh, f, length=131072)
            origen = "./"+document['name']
            shutil.move(origen, "./storingDir")

------------------------------------------code to procces the downloaded data--------------------------



[...]


------------------------------------------getting the sharable link-------------------------------
[...]
```

i was reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#methods) but i cant understand how to get the link with webViewLink

Comment: Is it not at `document['webViewLink']`?

Comment: You know there is no guarantee that the webViewLink wont change in the future right?  like say the next time you update the file.

Comment: What is `some documents`? Can I ask you about the mimeType of them?

Comment: i just realized that i had to include webViewLink in fields to be callable in document["webviewlink] thanks you a lot @RandomDavis

Answer (score 1):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As you already noticed, `webViewLink` is not returned by default when calling [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get):

> the `files.get` method might only return the `id`, `name`, and `mimeType` for the `files` resource.

In order to return specific fields, you have to set those in the `fields` parameter of your request.

In this case, it could be something like:

```
fields='files(id, name, parents, webViewLink)'
```

#### Reference:

- [Return specific fields for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/fields-parameter)